# Google Map interfering with clip-path CSS

Tags: html, css, google-maps, clip-path

I have a webpage where I have used clip-path on one section and used a simple google map for an entirely different section.

The desired effect using the clip path is:
[image: Desired Effect]

The CSS used in the first section is:

```
#frame2:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top: -200px;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff url('../images/hex1.png') no-repeat left 100px;
    clip-path:url(../images/frame.svg#clipPath);  /*Firefox*/
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0% 25%, 33% 99%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

While the CSS for google maps is:

```
#map{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Now, whenever I hide the map by either CSS or simply removing the map from the file, I get the desired effect, but when the map is there, the code behaves weird, the clipping section renders different with every reload.

Even, when I switch tabs and come back, it changes. Somewhat like this:
[image: Unpredictable Output]

Or this:

[image: Unpredictable Output 2]

Any help would be appreciated!

**P.S. I don't even have a black background anywhere. The CSS is properly reset.**

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem so +1, did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but @CyrilMestrom it appeared as if I was using redundant resources as I was using a png for background and and SVG for clipping. Instead, I used an SVG with the exact shape positioned/flex-boxed.